# Почему неправильно работает debounce?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не срабатывает debounce

```js
function debounce(func){
  var timer;
  return function(event){
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(func,300,event);
  };
}

$(window).on("resize",debounce(function(e){
  if ($('body, html').width() < 768) {
   $('.credit-type-list__title').on("click", function() {
     console.log("click");
     $(this).nextAll('ul').children('.item').slideToggle();
     $(this).children('img').toggleClass("active");
   });
  }
}));
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что неправильно работает?

Comment: .toggleClass срабатывает несколько раз

Comment: Ну это нормально. Вы знаете, зачем `debounce` используют?

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю (дальше своими словами) вызов функции происходит не постоянно, а только при следующем обращении ну и какой то промежуток времени. Как то так я понимаю из того, что читал в интернете. Ну а используют чтоб не загружать сайта, чтоб не было постоянного вызова функции

Comment: Подскажите как можно реализовать при resize только один вызов

Comment: *Подскажите как можно реализовать при resize только один вызов* - недостаточно данных для помощи. Я не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под *только один вызов*

Comment: При телефонном разрешении данные меню скрываются, и открываются при нажатии на стрелку, но когда я нажимаю меню открывается и сразу закрывается, а я хочу чтоб при первом нажатии  открывалось при втором закрывалось (скрывалось)

Comment: Теперь более-менее понятно. Проблема в том, что вы при ресайзе окна навешиваете событие `click`. Получается, что обработчиков `click` может быть очень много. Вам надо сделать обработчик на кнопку вне события ресайза.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать